# Recording location when adding to a TreeSet

Tags: java, treeset

I have a List with about 20,000,000 entries. About 5,000,000 entries are unique. I need to iterate over my List, identify unique entries, and assign each an integer between 0 and 5,000,000.

Currently, I sequentially add each entry to a TreeSet, then figure out where it went using .headSet(). I imagine this is suboptimal.

```
    while((nextline = wholefile.listIterator().next()) != null){

        //sorted, unique, addition
        keywords.add(nextline);

        //hmmm, get index of element in TreeSet?
        k_j = keywords.headSet(nextline).size();

    }
```

Is there a way to get the location when I call .add() ?

Comment: Instead of a List, why don't you use a Set?

Comment: I am simplifying a bit. I actually have a List<String[]> and I am only concerned uniqueness in the first entry of the string. The other entries will not be unique, but I will still need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do as follows:

1. Count the objects by populating a `Map<YourObject, Integer>`.
2. Go through this map and assign a sequence number to each key which maps to the value 1.

In code...

```
List<String> keywords = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "a");

Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String str : keywords) {
    if (!counts.containsKey(str))
        counts.put(str, 0);

    counts.put(str, counts.get(str) + 1);
}

int seq = 0;
for (String keyword : counts.keySet())
    if (counts.get(keyword) == 1)                      // is unique?
        System.out.println(keyword + " -> " + seq++);  // assign id.
```

Comment: Thanks. Having the syntax there really helps.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use a counter and `HashMap<Keyword, Integer>`. For each keyword in the list, get its position from the map. If you get null, put the keyword in the map with the current counter value as value, and increment the counter.